# ASP.NET MVC NullReferenceException only thrown when running, and when adding breakpoint the exception is not thrown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, debugging, breakpoints

See title.  Also, I tried adding a breakpoint and skipped quick (F10), but it did not throw either.

Here is the code that throws (see code comment):

```
public static double GetTotalExpenses(Sandooq sandooq, string userID = "")
{
    double totalExpenses = 0;

    if (sandooq.expenses == null || sandooq.expenses.Count == 0 ||
       (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID) && 
        sandooq.expenses.Where(i => i.member.Id.Equals(userID)).Count() == 0))
    {
        return totalExpenses;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userID))
    {
        foreach (Expense e in sandooq.expenses.Where(e => e.member.Id.Equals(userID) && 
                 !e.category.mainCategoryType.Equals("DPE")))
        {
            totalExpenses += e.amount;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // the error happens here; e.category is null 
        foreach (Expense e in sandooq.expenses.Where(e=>
                 !e.category.mainCategoryType.Equals("DPE")))
        {
            totalExpenses += e.amount;
        }
    }

    return totalExpenses;
}
```

**The category of the expense is null only when there is no breakpoint set.**

---

### EDIT

**I managed to solve the problem** by loading the list of 'expenses' from the database and include 'category'; by adding this line

```
sandooq.expenses = dbContext.dbExpenses.Include("category").Where(e => e.sandooq.id == sandooq.id).ToList();
```

Comment: From what you know about the data, is it actually null or not?  Does it behave correctly if you modify it like this?: `foreach (Expense e in sandooq.expenses.Where(e => e != null &&  !e.category.mainCategoryType.Equals("DPE")))`

Comment: In the database its not null, and its not suppose to be null, when i do as u suggested the error doesnt show but results are incorrect. I noticed when i hover on the object 'sandooq' and look at the list 'expenses' its not null, and then it works fine. thats really strange !